# How to solve this Python string interpolate related?

Tags: python, string-interpolation

I'm required to do a python quiz.

here is question:

> Your challenge here is to write a function format_point that returns a
>   string representing a point in 2-space. The function takes three
>   parameters. The first two are floating point numbers representing the
>   x and y coordinates of a point and the third parameter is an integer
>   specifying the required number of digits after the decimal point. The
>   returned string is of the form "(23.176, 19.235)". For example, the
>   following three lines of code should print the output (0.67, 17.12).

What I did was:

```
>>> def coordinate(x,y,n):
...     str_x = format(x,"."+n+"f")
...     str_y = format(y,"."+n+"f")
...     print("("+str_x+","+str_y+")")
... 
>>> coordinate(10.242,53.124,2)
```

I got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in coordinate
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

Where I did wrong?

Comment: As this looks like homework I won't give an answer, but check out type-casting in [Python](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#str).

Comment: look at string formatting its typically `"<SomeFormatString>".format(arg1,arg2,...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Try

```
format(str(x), "." + str(n) + "f")
```

or

```
format(str(x), ".%sf" % n)
```

Comment: Now It works! BTW your 2nd solution is pretty cool, could you give me some resource about it?

Comment: @yozloy check this  http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax